# SQL Statement; Help Writing Command for Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, command, iseries-navigator

I have been using Crystal Reports for a few years, but I have avoided using "Add Command" until now.

I have a report that generates an order confirmation. I want to schedule the confirmations to print at certain intervals, but in order to do that, I need a date/time that the order was last modified. That information can be found in an audit table, however, the audit table can contain multiple copies of the same order depending on how many times it has been modified. I cannot join directly to this audit table because it creates duplicate lines on my order acknowledgement, and while I can gather the needed information from the audit table in a subreport, I can't filter my main report on those results.

I want to take the audit table and only bring over the most recent record for each order so that I can filter on edit date and time.

Can anyone help with writing this statement?

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT "OEP40A"."ORDN40", "OEP40A"."ADAT40", "OEP40A"."ATIM40", "OEP40A"."APRG40", "OEP40A"."ARCT40"
 FROM   "S103EC55"."OSLD1F3"."OEP40A" "OEP40A"
 WHERE  "OEP40A"."ARCT40"='2' AND "OEP40A"."APRG40"='OE340'
 ORDER BY "OEP40A"."ORDN40", "OEP40A"."ADAT40" DESC, "OEP40A"."ATIM40" DESC
```

The order number is OEP40A.ORDN40. One of the issue that I have is that the date (OEP40A.ADAT40) and time (OEP40A.ATIM40) are separate fields. How do I select the record with the max date and time when those fields are separate? Will the statement above accomplish that by always sorting first on the date and then on the time?

Edited to add:

My server is an IBM iSeries running V5R4. Here's the solution I came up with in case anyone else should need it.

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by osld1f3.oep40a.ordn40 order by osld1f3.oep40a.adat40, osld1f3.oep40a.atim40 desc) as COUNT, osld1f3.oep40a.cono40, osld1f3.oep40a.adat40, osld1f3.oep40a.ordn40, osld1f3.oep40a.atim40

FROM osld1f3.oep40a

WHERE osld1f3.oep40a.arct40=2 and osld1f3.oep40a.aprg40='OE340' and osld1f3.oep40a.actf40<>'X'

Answer (score 0):

1. For maximum chance to help, you should provide the create table scripts for the tables in question.
2. As an aside, since you are using the Command approach, get your query working perfectly in your target database (Oracle, SQL Server) first before running the command in Crystal (if you can). It is easier to debug that way.
3. Regarding grabbing the latest record, you could a subquery like this if your table is using a sequential primary key:

`select z.claim_id, z.ASSIGN_ID from 
  (select c.claim_id
  ,  (select max(key_id) from audit_table ca where ca.fk_Id = c.fk_id) ASSIGN_ID
  from primary_table c) Z`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Douglas. I should have provided more information initially, but your post did point me in right direction. I will post my final solution above for anyone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your issue to my knowledge you don't need to write command to achieve the desired result.

try below process:

1. First create a `datetime` from `Date` and `Time` using `DateTimeValue (date, time)`. Check below link

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4JCV_7.5.5/com.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.designer.doc/html/topic664.html

2. Now create a group with order number and place the the created `Datetime` value in details.

By this you have different records of datetime in details of that order group.

3. Supress Details and take the maximum of the datetime by right clicking on the datetime field, which will give you the recent occurance.
4. Before doing all this stuff link tables using order number in database expert.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think this will work for me in this case. If I link the tables directly in Database Expert, I will get duplicate records for every line item on the order equal to the number of times the order has been modified. I need to select the latest record from OEP40A before linking to the order acknowledgement in Crystal Reports.

Comment: To get the latest record we are using maximum function